# is there a way to pre-authorize windows app for internet access?

Tags: windows, sockets, security, ftp

Sorry if there is a better place to ask this question...

I've added an FTP subsystem interface to our app - so that our scripts can download some files from our ftp server in order to determine whether a new version is available...

But when this is executed, Windows issues a security prompt - can this app be allowed...

Which apparently sometimes appears underneath our app window...

So, better than all of that mess would be to have our app authorized at install time.  But is there a way to do this?  And if not, then how do other apps which use the internet not constantly show this dialog (as an obvious example: Chrome)?

Surely there is a way to mark / register / authorize the app at installation time to bypass this security warning on every attempt to check for a new release?

I've tried a number of 'net searches without useful results, so I must be coming at this issue from an unusual direction?

Comment: Assuming that you're talking about a desktop application, and not a Modern App, that security prompt is offering to add a Windows firewall exception.  If you configure the Windows firewall appropriately during installation, the prompt will not appear.  I'm not familiar with the API myself, but [try a search on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=windows%20firewall%20api&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4).

Comment: That sounds promising.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others are looking for a solution - this is the core of what I came up with:

```
CComPtr<INetFwProfile> GetCurrentFirewallProfile()
{
    // we need the manager...
    CComPtr<INetFwMgr> pMgr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetFwMgr), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMgr));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw CComException(_T("Unable to create INetFwMgr instance"), hr);

    // ...to get the current policy...
    CComPtr<INetFwPolicy> pPolicy;
    hr = pMgr->get_LocalPolicy(&pPolicy);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw CComException(_T("Unable to obtain the INetFwPolicy from the INetFwMgr"), hr);

    // ...to get the current profile
    CComPtr<INetFwProfile> pProfile;
    hr = pPolicy->get_CurrentProfile(&pProfile);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw CComException(_T("Unable to obtain the INetFwProfile from the INetFwPolicy"), hr);

    return pProfile;
}

void AuthorizeAppInWindowsFirewall(CComPtr<INetFwProfile> pProfile, const CString executable, const CString name)
{
    // check if this app is already listed
    CComPtr<INetFwAuthorizedApplications> pApps;
    HRESULT hr = pProfile->get_AuthorizedApplications(&pApps);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw CComException(_T("Unable to obtain the INetFwAuthorizedApplications from the INetFwProfile"), hr);

    // allocate a com string for our app name
    CComBSTR bstrExecutable(executable);

    CComPtr<INetFwAuthorizedApplication> pApp;
    hr = pApps->Item(bstrExecutable, &pApp);
    if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
    {
        // create one for our app
        hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetFwAuthorizedApplication), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pApp));
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw CComException(_T("Unable to create INetFwAuthorizedApplication instance"), hr);

        // Set the file name
        hr = pApp->put_ProcessImageFileName(bstrExecutable);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw CComException(_T("INetFwAuthorizedApplication::put_ProcessImageFileName failed:"), hr);

        // set the application friendly name
        CComBSTR bstrName(name);
        hr = pApp->put_Name(bstrName);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw CComException(_T("INetFwAuthorizedApplication::put_Name failed:"), hr);

        // add to list
        hr = pApps->Add(pApp);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw CComException(_T("INetFwAuthorizedApplications::Add failed:"), hr);
    }
    else if (FAILED(hr))
        throw CComException(_T("INetFwAuthorizedApplications::Item failed:"), hr);

    // it's already in the list - ensure it is enabled
    VARIANT_BOOL bEnabled;
    hr = pApp->get_Enabled(&bEnabled);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw CComException(_T("INetFwAuthorizedApplication::get_Enabled failed:"), hr);

    // not enabled?
    if (bEnabled == VARIANT_FALSE)
    {
        // disabled - let's attempt to enable it!
        hr = pApp->put_Enabled(VARIANT_TRUE);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw CComException(_T("INetFwAuthorizedApplication::put_Enabled failed:"), hr);
    }
}
```